# foundation5 menu always responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation-5

I am using foundation5 for responsivenes in my wordpress theme.
How do i define in foundation5 the menu to look responsive even in large resolution.
Currently it is collapsed up until 73.2142857143em.
I want the menu to be collapsed always, even for width 2000em.

Here my html.

```
<section id="navBar">
<div class="contain-to-grid clearfix sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="sticky_on: large;">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">logo</li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="top-bar-menu left"><li id="menu-item-567" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item active menu-item-567 active"><a href="http://url.loc/coming-soon/">Search</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-570" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-570"><a href="http://url.loc/kategorie/">Category</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-584" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-584"><a href="http://url.loc/faq/">Faq</a></li>
            </ul>                       </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help if you added the css, but all you would have to do is change the media query value to the width you want the menu to be responsive,, or just replace the existing menu css with the css inside the media query so it will always be responsive

Comment: The css is a unmodified foundation5 css (i didnt include it as its too big and it would be not very clever). Anyway both things you mentioned i tried, but the css solution didnt work, it just adapts my view. That means by addapting the media (gui) menu icon is visible in large resolution as i wanted BUT the probem is it is not clickable. Javascript on that element is just not working (not triggering the open menu action). So i came to a conclusion it must be done in a different way, not by modifying the css @media.

Comment: So the behaviour than is ... i see always menu icon, but it opens only when i am below 73.2142857143em :) so i have to shrink the window to see the menu :)

Comment: if anybody knows about an example in foundation5 where the menu stays collapsed always, even for large resolution, send me a link i will check it myself ... unfortunatelly i didnt find any example of that type and that type of framework version, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Foundation 5.5.3, you can change the topbar breakpoint width by updating **foundation.css**. In the following two places, I'm changing the breakpoint to 9999px (or whatever you want):

Change the width of media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 9999px) {
  .top-bar {
    ...blah.blah.blah
```

and this style

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:9999px)/";
  width: 9999px;
}
```

That should work, but if it doesn't, let us know what version of Foundation 5 you're using (in the wordpress theme).

Comment: Reference this thread: [Changing Topbar breakpoint using css](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1053-changing-topbar-breakpoint-using-css)